# How to extend the SLDS Grid with additional x-large and xx-large breakpoints to support huge screens?

Tags: slds, slds-grid

I need a grid having 1 columns for phones 2 columns for ipads and 3 columns on 1080p screens. I will also need more distinction for devices between 1000px and 3000px in screen-width. How to do that with vanilla SLDS?

What I've tried so far on the grid elements so far is

```
slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_2-of-4 slds-large-size_1-of-3
```

Works to distinct phones. But the breakpoint for large is to small. ipad will end up as being "large".

a) I need the ipad different of desktop 
b) i need to distinct between small desktop (e.g. width 1024 to 1400px) screen, bigger screens (eg. width 1400 to 1920px) and huge desktop screens (>1920px).

Actually the 3 sizes give me control over

- small < 768px
- medium < 1024px
- large >= 1024px

By far not enough.

So I thought there should be something like x-large and xx-large. Is that stuff existing and usable?

I've tried without success:

```
slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_2-of-4 slds-x-large-size_1-of-3
```

this fails, too

```
slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_2-of-4 slds-x_large-size_1-of-3
```

and this fails, too

```
slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_2-of-4 slds-xlarge-size_1-of-3
```

how to use x-large and xx-large?

how to extend it if xx-large would not be enough? eg. if I would need xxx-large or xxxx-large to distinct between the super huge screens?

**CURRENT WORKAROUND**

My current workaround is to calculate my desired column-count in the controller and to apply it via the class-attribute dynamically like this

```
    class = "{!''
        +' whateverClassName '
        +' slds-large-size_1-of-'   + v.layoutLargeColumnCount + ' '
    }"
```

It works, but I hate this approach and would love to replace it by something else.

**SCREENSHOTS**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, grids only support the three breakpoints, 480, 768, and 1024. If you want any other type of design, you'll have to build your own.

Comment: @sfdcfox I see, and I did. Basically I'm down to `'slds-size_1-of-'+v.layoutColumnCount` - but I still think that is poor design provided by salesforce. Now I have to take care of rerenderings, window-resizings and other stuff always applying my custom "How-Many-Cols-Do-I-Have?-Logic" and that's error-prone. Delivering good and distinctive UX for super huge screens is IMHO exactly as important as providing good UX for phones or tablets. Any-Device-First, so to say...

Answer (score 1):

> but I still think that is poor design provided by salesforce. Now I
>   have to take care of rerenderings, window-resizings and other stuff
>   always applying my custom "How-Many-Cols-Do-I-Have?-Logic" and that's
>   error-prone.

TRUE! it will be too complicated with `slds-size_1-of-'+v.layoutColumnCount'` approach.

So, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for fully custom/simple yet powerful solution. You can use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) guide to begin with.

I also created [this playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/F0ho6op4S/2/edit) for you.

**When width is > 700px:**
[image]

**When width is < 700px:**
[image]

**When width is << 700px:**
[image]

Comment: I agree that this looks like a way cleaner approach, but I would need a lot more to get something like the grid system with a bottom-up approach. Would feel like reinventing the wheel. My guess is, that there is a way to extend the grid system with additional breakpoints. But I think salesforce should do that for us to encourage and support us to create an exceptional UX for huge screens in a way that the display "real estate" is used dynamically and smoothly. With the given 3 breakpoints focusing mainly mobile devices, that is simply not powerful enough.